# Calculating a Web Audio API filter's response at a specific frequency and Q-factor

Tags: math, audio, canvas, signal-processing, web-audio-api

I'm using the Web Audio API to make a graphic EQ with four BiQuad filters; a highpass, two bandpass and a low pass:

[image]

You can see each node representing each filter's frequency. It's working nicely but I'd like to draw the shape of the filter's roll-off you'd usually find in other graphic EQ's.

I have the Q-factor of each filter and the central frequency. What I would like to do is get a formula that allows me to get the frequency of the roll-off at a specific db value. For example what is the frequency of the roll-off at -200db?

It's been a while since I've done any heavy mathematical stuff and so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might also try asking this on http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question might be helpful: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/plotting-the-magnitude-response-of-a-biquad-filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the getFrequencyResponse method of BiquadFilterNode?  https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#Methods.

This demo from my IO2012 Web Audio talk uses it: http://webaudio-io2012.appspot.com/frames/frequency-response.html.  You'll have to calculate the responses of multiple filters stacked together from there, of course.